# constantly changing value printed out as "SYNCHRONIZING" on Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple web scraper using Python as I'm trying to learn it, but when I try to print out the time header using BeautifulSoup, it just gives me a "SYNCHRONIZING" instead of actually displaying the time at the exact point I clicked "Build". I am interested in making this a live web scraper so if anyone could help me out with that I would appreciate it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.time.gov/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

t3 = soup.find('div', {"clock-box yellow dst-clock"})

t2 = t3.find_all('time')



print(t2)
```

Comment: Kindly mark the answer accepted if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's because this is exactly what the HTML source contains - it looks like this:

```
<div class="clock-box yellow dst-clock">
    <div class="title">Central <span class="DSTterm">Standard</span> Time</div>
        <div class="sub-title">C<span class="DSTletter">S</span>T (UTC-<span class="DSTnum">6</span>)</div>
            <div class="time-display">
                <div class="color-area"></div>
                    <div class="clock time-text"><time zoneOffset=6>SYNCHRONIZING</time></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The time you see is **not** part of HTML, it is displayed by a JavaScript snippet. You can't "scrape" it.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for asking basic questions.